# Is there a way to override Font.Position increments to make them smaller (to less than.5 pt)? With VBA or otherwise?

Tags: c++, vba, ms-word

I'm writing a VBA macro in Word(365) which loops through a selection character by character and randomizes font position (raise/lower) and spacing*. I know what you're thinking, and yes, this makes the final .docx file size *much* larger than the original.

*Context: Why? I'm a hobbyist book designer/poet/editor trying to mimic the warmth/analog/organic feel (and subtle inherent flaws) of hand-set letterpress type.

So, here's the deal: The code works. That's not the problem.

The problem is that Word's Font.Position increments are hard-coded at .5 pt, so when my macro calculates the random position, Word rounds it to the nearest .5 pt. That is just too large for what I need with my small fonts (usually 12 pt). I may be on a wild goose chase, but is there any way to override these increments, via VBA (ideally) or otherwise (C++?), to make them smaller for a more subtle effect?

Note: The Font.Spacing increments are .05 pt, so that's not a problem, just Font.Position.

I was also monkeying around with the page size, thinking that I could just make a huge page & font size (ie: 1000%), to make up for the too-large .5 pt increments, and then scale it back down (to 10%) to its intended size in a PDF, but the limit on page size is a mere 22" which is not big enough to make much of a difference.

My next option is to translate the same macro into LibreOffice Writer. That program uses integer % increments instead of .5 pt increments, which would be about 4x more precise @ 12 pt font (.12 pt increments). As such, Writer would out perform Word in this application until the font size is 50 pt or larger. I do not have much experience with LO Basic, and documentation/example code is much harder to come by. I know it's very similar to VBA and there's a lot of crossover. It might/might not be an easy project, I just haven't tried yet.

Anyway, I wanted to see if there was a way around the increments in Word first because I'd like to have this application within both Word and Writer.

Right now, I'm under the assumption that the increments are hard-coded into Word and there's nothing I can do about it.

Prove me wrong.

Thanks!

P.S. I know nothing about C++ and if everyone tells me that Word is a lost cause and I should just translate it to Writer I'll do that (I may anyway) and post my code for that later if I get stuck.

Comment: "prove me wrong" sounds like your posting on social media and not on a serious forum where you're asking for help.  In any case whats your VBA code you have where the issue arises?

Comment: Sorry for my often ill-advised sense of humor. Just being cheeky.

Comment: Its all good.  If you post sample of your VBA code where you're experiencing issues then we can help further.

Comment: 0.5 point is the minimum. In general, if you can't do it in the user interface, you can't do it in code either.

Comment: @CAM_344 I'm away from my VBA code at the moment, but again, the problem, as John Korchok is confirming, is with the limitatons of the minimum increments, not the code. For instance with 12 pt font, let's say I want to set the position range to 10% of font size with 10 steps of randomness.
1: .12 pt (Word rounds to 0 pt or Normal)
2: .24 pt (Word rounds to 0 pt or Normal)
3: .36 pt (Word rounds to .5 pt)
4: .48 pt (Word rounds to .5 pt)
5: .6 pt (Word rounds to .5 pt)
6: .72 pt (Word rounds to .5 pt)
7: .84 pt (Word rounds to 1 pt) etc, and so on...
I now have 3 positions, not 10.

Comment: @JohnKorchok I was afraid of that, but I am not surprised.

Comment: Could you use a larger page size and fonts, then scale down the view zoom ?  Then you should get finer control if the main issue is the 0.5pt increment.

Comment: @TimWilliams already tried that. See OP. Word has a 22" page size limit on documents. Not big enough for what I want.

Comment: To be clear, the 1% increments in LibreOffice Writer are *better*, but still not as precise as I want. Page size/font size/resize document won't have any effect on a %. I may just have to live with it.

Comment: Sorry - did not read the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

Completely nonsense. According to VBA Word reference, property Font.Position is Long. This property sets the vertical alignment of a selected text above (or below) the line. In UI: Font-Advanced-Character Spacing-Position.

- Manually you can set this property with 0.5 rounding.
- Macro recording also shows command "Selection.Font.Position = 0.5"
- No way you can assign the property Font.Position with a fraction using macro, because it's Long.

I would like to have a macro shifting text above or below the line, but it is possible only to shift by step of 1.0 (or 0.5 via UI). Hope, there is a workaround... (at least for 0.5. Could you show you code example with 0.5 shift?)

**Updated** I have found a workaround. According to the old WordBasic reference - the minimum step for Position is 0.5 pt.

To get the value with 0.5 fraction (of the selected text. Font.Position returns Long with no fraction)

```
MsgBox Dialogs(wdDialogFormatFont).Position
```

To set the value with 0.5 fraction (to the selected text), you must use old-style WordBasic

```
WordBasic.FormatFont Position:="-0.5"
```

Hope, this helps somebody...

More about old WordBasic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/conceptual-differences-between-wordbasic-and-visual-basic
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/built-in-dialog-box-argument-lists-word